# Whats the difference in using "_predictions" and "self.predictions"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following the Treehouse tutorials, the app is supposed to access an array of strings and randomly return one upon the press of a button. I thought "_predictions" was the same thing as "self.predictions". When I changed all of the "self.predictions" to "_predictions" in the implementation of the NSString "randomPrediction", nothing was returned. What's the difference in using "self.predictions" and "_predictions"?

```
#import "SLWCrystallBall.h"

@implementation SLWCrystallBall

- (NSArray *) predictions {
    if (_predictions == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NBA team names accessed");
        _predictions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"The Oklahoma City Thunder", @"The San Antonio Spurs", @"The Miami Heat", 
            @"The Indiana Pacers", @"The Chicago Bulls", @"The Toronto Bulls", 
            @"The Boston Celtics", @"The Brooklyn Nets", @"The New York Knicks", 
            @"The Philadelphia 76ers", @"The Cleveland Cavaliers", @"The Detroit Pistons", 
            @"The Milwaukee Bucks", @"The Atlanta Hawks", @"The Charlotte Bobcats", 
            @"The Orlando Magic", @"The Washington Wizards", @"The Denver Nuggets", 
            @"The Minnesota Timberwolves", @"The Portland Trail Blazers", 
            @"The Utah Jazz", @"The Golden State Warriors", @"The Los Angeles Clippers", 
            @"The Los Angeles Lakers", @"The Phoenix Suns", @"The Sacramento Kings", 
            @"The Dallas Mavericks", @"The Houston Rockets", @"The Memphis Grizzlies", 
            @"The New Orleans Pelicans", nil];

    }
    NSLog(@"Team name returned");
    return _predictions;
}

- (NSString*) randomPrediction {
    int random = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)self.predictions.count);
    return [self.predictions objectAtIndex:random];
    NSLog(@"Random prediction created");
}

@end
```

Here is the header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SLWCrystallBall : NSObject {
    NSArray *_predictions;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *predictions;

- (NSString*) randomPrediction;


@end
```

Comment: Please search. There are plenty of duplicates of this question.

Comment: Crystal only has one "l".

Comment: I searched, but I couldn't find an answer that accommodated my level of experience. I know that "Crystall" is only supposed to have one "l". Can I change the name of a class after it's already been set? Thanks.

Comment: @SilentLoneWolf The best way to rename a class is using Xcode's [Refractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066163/rename-or-refactor-files-in-xcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_predictions` accesses the variable directly, while `self.predictions` calls an accessor instead.  You should use `self.predictions` because of memory management benefits.  In your case, the accessor creates the array, so it is practically necessary.  Please note that in your `-predictions` method, you must use `_predictions` otherwise your accessor will just call itself.